# how i can go in admin panel is it possible when use sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to access the sqlite admin at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin, but I don't know the user and pass.  During **python manage.py migrate**, it did not ask about new user.

Config:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.DEC_DB'),
}
```

Comment: which admin panel? there's more than just ONE admin panel in the universe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and create Django administrator first. Then you will be able to log-in to admin site using this account.

Comment: okok thanks, its work) as you understand im new and follow some tutorial didn't write about it

Comment: Here is more in-depth information about this command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser. Basically, it allows you to create basic user account with administrative right, necessary to log-in to admin site.